# The output always comes out to be an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Exercise 2: Write a program to look for lines of the form:

```
New Revision: 39772
```

Extract the number from each of the lines using a regular expression and the `findall()` method.

Compute the average of the numbers and print out the average.

The input file is "mbox-short.txt".

```
import re
fname=input("enter the file name:")
fhandle=open(fname)
total=0
count=0
for x in fhandle:
    y=re.findall("^New Revision:(\s [0-9]*) ",x)         
    total=total+y
    count=count+1
print(y)
print("total and average is:",total,total/count)
```

Also can anyone suggest that how to convert all the elements in the list to float

Comment: fyi there is a special character `\d` for `[0-9]`, more info at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex had a `' '` too much at its end, thats why it did never find something.

`findall()` with the pattern you startet will ever only return 1 hit (or 0 hits) - due to starting with `^`.

```
import re

fname=input("enter the file name:")
fhandle=open(fname)
total=0.0
count=0
for x in fhandle:
    y=re.findall(r"^New Revision:(\s*[0-9]*)",x)    # 0 or 1 hit  
    if y:  
        total += float(y [0] )               # to float if found 
        count += 1                           
print("total and average is:",total,total/count)
```

Example using a text:

```
t = """New Revision: 129
New Revision: 129
New Revision: 129
New Revision: 129
New Revision: 129
"""

import re 
total=0.0
count=0
for x in t.splitlines():
    y=re.findall("^New Revision:(\s*[0-9]*)",x)
    if y:
        total += float(y [0] )
        count += 1
print(y)
print("total and average is:",total,total/count)
```

Output:

```
total and average is: 645.0 129.0
```

Comment: BTW, you should add the generic `python` tag to Python questions that don't have it. It makes the question more visible, so the question & answer are more likely to get voted on. And you'll get your gold Python badge faster that way. ;)

Comment: @PM lol - forgot it, he unedited my first edit.Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: why if y: is used like I am confused about the role its playing in the script @PatrickArtner

Comment: `if y:` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing       -  empty lists, strings, tuples etc evaluate to `False` - if nomatch `findall()` returns empy list